# Visual Studio 2019 - C++ wstring assignment unexpected encoding

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, wstring

We are experiencing an unexpected problem when executing a simple assignment between two wstring objects in Visual Studio 2019.

Long code made short:

```
wstring source = L"Test-";
wstring dest;
dest = source;
```

After the assignment `dest` is not displayed by the debugger (and not even by the application being debugged) as 'Test-' but it is displayed as ideograms.

Comparing the strlen of `source.c_str()` and `dest.c_str()` yields a length of 5 for source and 3 for dest (this matches the number of ideograms being displayed)

Obviously this happens only in a single point of the code, and whereever else we assign wstrings we do not experience a similar issue. The unexpected behaviour happens in one specific point, which is the copy constructor of a class having a wstring member attribute.

Any hint on what could be the reason for this behaviour is very welcome

Thanks in advance

PS. following is a screenshot from the debugger:
[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code fragment. You might be experiencing a compiler bug. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I mean, except the fact that `wstring source = "Test-";` is not legal and should not compile. Maybe you meant `L"Test-"`?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. - I would love to try to build a minimal reproducible example, but any attempt, in creating it, has failed so far. The unexpected behaviour happens in one specific point, which is the copy constructor of a class having a wstring member attribute.

Comment: Sorry... about the wrong shortened code :) the screenshot shows the modified encoding after the assignment was executed

Comment: According to the screenshot, even the bytes are not corresponding. You want to provide the correct code, and try to test bits of it, because obviously, your repro is not correct (it works ie it does not reproduce the behavior).

Comment: It seems that you are inside a constructor of your custom class, if you post a simplified version of your class here we could find out something.